# Debugging flask application under Docker-compose

Tags: docker, flask, pycharm, dockerfile

I followed [Docker-Compose: Getting Flask up and running](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2017/03/docker-compose-getting-flask-up-and-running/) tutorial and tried to debug a flask application in `Pycharm`. To this end, I cloned [this](https://github.com/alfredfrancis/ai-chatbot-framework) repository and did all steps in tutorial (configure remote interpreter).

I guess `frontend` service (`iky-gateway`) not create successfully because when I go the `localhost:8080` nothing displayed.

[image]

console's log didn't show any error, Do I miss something that UI is not displayed?

---

If I set `frontend` as main Docker-compose services:

[image]

Then it throws following exception:

```
Cannot start service iky_gateway: b'OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \\"\\": executable file not found in
```

---

**Edit**: Even when I clicked on the UI button I got response (status code:200) in console but UI not displayed as expected.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the compose file in that project it looks like you might not be starting up the gateway service at all. I can see from your picture that you are attached to iky_backend. The compose file shows that iky_backend has a dependency on the mongo image which has also started up.

As you have attached to the iky_backend service that means you probably ran the equivalent of `docker-compose up iky_backend`. This will start the backend and mongo as there is a dependency, but will not start the gateway as there is no dependency.

```
services:
  iky_backend:
    container_name: iky_backend
    build: .
    environment:
      APPLICATION_ENV: Production
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
```

If you want to start all 3 services then try running `docker-compose up iky_gateway`. The gateway has a dependency on the backend and the backend has a dependency on mongo so all 3 will start and you will be attached to the console output for the gateway service.

You can use compose to see what is running using `docker-compose ps` and you can access logs using `docker-compose logs <service_name>`.

I'd suggest having a read of the [Docker Compose Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) or having a look at the help command for docker-compose to see some of the useful commands

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @Tim. Actually my problem is how to run all 3 services in Pycharm at the same time (attach 3 services in Pycharm interpreter). I have no problem with docker-compose. When I run docker-compose up everything is Okay.

Comment: @Amir which service from the compose file is currently set to run in your Pycharm configuration? It looks like you've set it to run the backend so the gateway will never start. If you change the service to run the gateway service all 3 services should run in Pycharm

Comment: After changing services from backend to gateway it throws an exception. pls see edited version of my question